# Microsoft.Web.Administration: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, iis-7, wmi

I use the `Windows.Web.Administration` dll in a C# program to manage IIS 7 (I use only the method `Recycle`).

The first problem was:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
```

And later I have added `NETWORK SERVICE` with full control at the folder  `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`".

Now I have this message error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostProperty.get_Value()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetPropertyValue(IAppHostProperty property)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetAttributeValue(String attributeName)
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool.get_State()
```

**How can I avoid this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your program as administrator, or if you are in VS run VS as administrator.

MWA requires administrator permissions to talk to IIS interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. I am not in VS. 
I don't know I can run the application as administrator. If not, I give in IIS the all permission to every user.

Comment: The message error appear in the browser, when I click on a button of the programm.

Comment: Sounds like your program is a web app on IIS whose pool identity is Network Service. It won't work that way and you have to change the identity to an administrator.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much to all!
It works: I change the identity of ApplicationPool in Administrator user.

Comment: Changing an app pool to run as local system or an administrator is a significant security risk and shouldn't be necessary. I'm running my app pool as a normal user account which is a member of IIS_IUSRS. If I run VS as administrator, I'm able to use MWA.

Comment: @RobertBratton It is a security risk, but could still be managed in many ways.